# Why Laravel's reset password feature uses database while email verification uses signed routes?

Tags: php, laravel, security

Laravel comes with two built-in features called [Forgot/Reset Password](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passwords#introduction) and [Email Verification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification#introduction).
We all know that both are very critical and sensitive operations for an application, so their security must be guaranteed by Laravel framework itself.

However, I got confused why forgot/reset password [uses a database table](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/tests/Database/migrations/one/2016_01_01_100000_create_password_resets_table.php#L16) to keep the tokens while email verification [uses signed routes](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/506eedbde5cf23c9dc20f2dd168b02a37e9b72bc/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php#L61) feature.

Note: Signed route/URL is a feature provided by Laravel itself. [See docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#signed-urls).

Is there any security or performance concerns here? When should we use which one then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject has already been discussed on one of Pull Requests on laravel/framework's repository. You can access it here:
[[5.7] Database-less Password Reset #23706](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23706)

To summarize, main concerns were these:

> - URLs can be replayed to reset the token again.
> - Ex-employee could immediately generate password reset links (valid ones) for any account in the system until the encryption keys are
>     rotated. Rotating these keys could be kind of a PITA if you're storing
>     other encrypted data. In a large, high-profile application this
>     becomes a huge source of pain and single point of failure.
> - Links can be essentially "guessed" forever; however, I'm not sure brute-forcing the keys generated by key:generate is realistic.

Answer (score 2):

Good point,  but then again there is a big difference in their usages.

- For the email verification you are already signed in and you just need to click the link in the email which will then store the time in the `users` table `email_verified_at` column when you performed the action. And this is used to verify that really the owner of the email has registered on your site or that the email is really valid, and not a fake email so someone takes advantage of your site.
- The forgot password option means that you don't remember your password (and you are logged out), and when you enter your email, the link sent to your email is again a signed route (has the token as the email verification does), but the link also contains the email address, so both the token and the email must match a row in the `password_resets` table in order to allow the user to change the password.

Having said all of this, I believe it is pretty secure, never had a problem with both. So this is my 2 cents regarding the question, hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation however, it's still ambiguous to me. Signed routes doesn't require user to be logged in so basically it can be used for forgot password too.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by signed route, but the password/reset is also a signed route. You've got the token in the route and the email as well. Both need to match a record in the database. The usage is completely different. If you verified your email there is `email_verified_at` column in the users table, and if you reset the password again needs to match a record in the DB. So both use the database once again.

Comment: Ok, by signed route/URL, I mean [this particular feature](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#signed-urls) provided by Laravel. Dealing with `email_verified_at` is a post-verification action which is not the subject of the question. I'm asking about the actual mechanism of verification and resetting using URLs.